# Checking to see if a value exists in Javascript

Tags: jquery

How do I check if a given variable has a value?  What is the JS equivalent of PHP's isset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (myVariable === undefined) {
    // myVariable has not been assigned a value...
}
```

Also, this same question was asked and answered here on Stackoverflow. [See, How can I determine if a JavaScript variable is defined in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138669/how-can-i-determine-if-a-javascript-variable-is-defined-in-a-page)

Comment: Is this how you do if it is not undefined?  if (myVariable !== undefined) {
    // myVariable has not been assigned a value...
}

Comment: @shummel: Sure, that would work. You could also do: `if (!(myVariable === undefined)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof variable === "undefined") {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: this will return true also for non existing variables

Comment: Non-existing variables probably don't have a value.

Comment: Non-existing variables don't exist, the question was about a given variable.