# typeof usage for undefined variables

Tags: javascript, typeof

what is the best usage for the "**typeof**" JavaScript function?

```
if (typeof (myvar) == 'undefined') { 
//or
if (typeof (myvar) == undefined) { 
//or
if (typeof myvar == 'undefined') { 
//or
if (typeof myvar == undefined) {
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you doing this? you should just do `myvar === undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if a JavaScript variable is defined in a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138669/how-can-i-determine-if-a-javascript-variable-is-defined-in-a-page)

Comment: @DanielA.White If `myvar` hasn't been declared, your code would throw `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`typeof` is an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof), not a function, and returns a *string*; so **do not** use parentheses and **do** compare it to a string.

When you compare things, avoid type coercion unless you need it (i.e. use `===` not `==`).

```
if (typeof myvar === 'undefined') {
```

Answer (score 4):

Use strict comparison (`===`), and quote `"undefined"`:

```
if (typeof myvar === "undefined") {}
```