# if statements with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

[Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230470/how-to-use-if-statements-in-underscore-js-templates) is very similar, but not quite the same.]

I'm trying to do `if` statements with underscore templates. I have tried:

```
<% if (_id) { %><%=_id %><% } %>
```

and

```
<% if (_id) { _id } %>
```

and

```
<% if (_id) { <%= _id %> } %>
```

and a bunch of other combinations, but I always get the error

> ReferenceError: _id is not defined

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what is your code, but `_id` is obviously an identifier. The problem, though, that you do not have `_id` defined.

As for suggestion, I'd probably suggest that you define it or use the one that is defined. It's hard to give you a better suggestion with zero context.

**EDIT**: you probably want `if(typeof _id != 'undefined')` instead.

Comment: Here is the context. I render the template by passing an object wit properties. It turns out that sometimes `_id` is not one of the properties of that object. In that case, I just want to show nothing, but not error out.

Comment: Because if you reference undefined variable you get the not defined error with some javascript engines.

Comment: Aha. Could you link to further information regarding this. Because I constantly use the pattern `if(variable) { ... }` where `variable` could be `undefined`?

Comment: Here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138669/how-can-i-determine-if-a-javascript-variable-is-defined-in-a-page ? :)

Comment: You probably refer to object properties (`if(a.b)`) or function parameters. I think it works better in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but this is how I solved a similar problem:

inside your model:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        field1: null
    }

});
```

then in your template you can do:

```
<% if (field1) { %>
    ...
<% } else { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```